# Python VENV. Is there any way I can use variables in pyvenv.cfg file?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv

I have a parameter of an interpreter path in pyvenv.cfg file:

```
executable = C:\Users\Stanislav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
```

Is there any way I can use a variable like %USERPROFILE% or similar to dynamically change the current user folder where python interpreter is installed ?

```
executable = %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local ...........
```

But I want to do that without the need of creation the new pyvenv.cfg file on-the-fly when running activate.bat

The reason for that is that my project files are located in Onedrive cloud and I am working on them from different machines which have different usernames (Stanislav-work, Stanislav-home etc.), so when I activate the current environment, I get the message that no python is installed and I need to edit the path in this file manually to get it work

Maybe i could parse these variables by the file which uses that pyvenv.cfg?

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible to use variables in a `pyvenv.cfg` file.

Comment: Just create a different virtual environment on each machine instead of trying to share one on the remote drive.

Comment: `activate.bat` is just like any batch file. you can edit the file and add any command you want, write a python script that generates the `pyvenv.cfg` from a template string, call this script in the `activate.bat`

Comment: if i create a different virtual environment on each machine then i need manually to update files in each of that environment every time i work in it, but i want just to get to my office, turn on PC and work on files which i did not finish at home :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeap, the only way to do that is to create a new pyvenv.cfg file on-the-fly
every time the virtual environment is activated:

```
$PROJECT_DIR = Split-Path (Split-Path (Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent) -Parent) -Parent

$pythonVersion = (Get-Content $PROJECT_DIR\.venv\pyvenv.cfg | Select-String 'version = ').ToString().Split('=')[1].Trim()

$pythonVersion = $pythonVersion.Replace('"', '')

$pythonFolder = 'python' + $pythonVersion.Split('.')[0] + $pythonVersion.Split('.')[1]

$pyvenvContent = @"
home = C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\$pythonFolder
include-system-site-packages = false
version = $pythonVersion
executable = C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\$pythonFolder\python.exe
"@ 

New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$PROJECT_DIR\.venv" -Force

$pyvenvContent | Out-File -FilePath "$PROJECT_DIR\.venv\pyvenv.cfg" -Encoding utf8

$env:PATH = "$PROJECT_DIR\.venv\Scripts;$env:PATH"

Set-Location $PROJECT_DIR
```

Just need to add that at the end of the Activate.ps1 file . It gets a current path of project folder (2 levels up from activate.ps1 file location) into $PROJECT_DIR variable which is then used as a default location in powershell or terminal when the venv is activated (so you do not need to run 'cd /current_project_location')
It gets the python version from a previous pyvenv.cfg file and format it to get the proper directory name (from 3.10.11 to python310) so I can use it with every python version and any user name